# OnItemClickListener doesn't work but OnLongItemClickListener works in Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a custom `listview` with custom adapter. I want to click on the items of `listview` and do something. The `OnItemClickListener` does not works. But I implemented `OnLongItemClickListener`and it works perfectly.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
Adapter listviewAdapter;  //custom adapter object
ListView listview; 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    listview.setLongClickable(true);
    listviewAdapter = new Adapter(this, products);      
    listview.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);    
   listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {  //this works
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});      
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {    //does not work
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});     
}
```

**UPDATE** custom adapter **Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;
TextView itemname,itemprice;
Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }
    Product p = getProduct(position);
     itemname= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr));
     itemname.setText(p.name);
     itemprice=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice));
     itemprice.setText(p.price + "");
    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    cbBuy.setTag(position);
    cbBuy.setChecked(p.selected);       
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });       
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });     
    return view;
}
Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
}
ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Product> selected = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product p : objects) {
        if (p.selected)
            selected.add(p);
    }
    return selected;
}
OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).selected = isChecked;
    }
};
```

}

custom listview **item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/cbBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
</CheckBox>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""  >
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:longClickable="true">
</ListView>
```

Comment: can You share the complete adapter code please?

Comment: updated the adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amsheer your code works. But for that you had to change the custom adapter and write the actions for `onClick` events in it. I wanted to write the `onClick` events in the ManiActivity. I found a workaround. I removed this from custom adapter

```
 view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

THis is because of your CheckBox. You can solve like this:

Add an id to your Linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:id="@+id/main_layout">
```

And in your getView

```
LinearLayout main_layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout));

main_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                listview .performItemClick(view,
                                        listview.getPositionForView(view),
                                        listview.getPositionForView(view));

                            }
                        });
```

Edit:
Use following code for long click

```
main_layout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                                listview.performLongClick();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: by doing this `OnItemLongClickListner` gets disabled

Comment: ya.. in my custom adapter i wrote your code `LinearLayout main_layout= (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        main_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), " pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });` By this `onItemclick` now works but my previous `OnItemLongClickListner` doesn't work now.

Comment: Infact in `onItemLongClick` too your code gets fired.

Comment: Then do one thing setOnLongClick for that main_layout. I add code in edit check that.

Comment: Now both `onItemLongClick` and `onItemClick` gets fired sequentially after long press of item row.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad minor issue. in main_layout .setOnLongClickListener change return method to true;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77615/discussion-between-amsheer-and-ted).

Comment: Thanks.Your code works. But I found out a workaround.See my ans.

Comment: That is exactly my answer right? This performItemClick and performLongClick is used to trigger the actions.

Answer (score 1):

to your text views and check box

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: I tried it doesn't work `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Answer (score 1):

You can give `android:onClick` attribute in xml :

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/cbBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />
```

This will work when you check or uncheck Checkbox.

**Reason** why onClick do not work, but onLongClick works :

You have applied `onListItemClickListener` over your list view row so when you were clicking on checkbox, the event was consumed by this listener

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

**Update :**

in `getView()` :

```
    // for list row
 view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("onClick","row click");

        }
});   

    // for list row check box
 view.cbBuy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Log.d("onClick","checkbox click");

        }
});
```

**In MainActivity** :

Remove this part :

```
/*   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {    //does not work
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); */
```

Whether checkbox has property `android:focusable="true"` or `false` this code will run
This is working compiled and run code
Thank you

Comment: i want to keep seperate the `CheckBox` `onClick` event and `Listview` row `onClick` event. This doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: I have **Updated** my answer.. this is running code